# Is there any merit to a web developer learning C?

Tags: c#, python, c

I have been working as a web dev with C#, VB and PHP (now learning python)..

I have been considering learning C (as a right of passage) because i hate feeling stupid =P

Apart from making me a better programmer in general..

Is there any particualr use to C for a Web Dev in 2010?

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: One can always hope to elevate oneself above one's station.

Answer (score 4):

Learning C (or, for the added fun, C++) as a device of increasing your understanding of programming is a good idea IMHO. But it doesn't have anything to offer you as regards web development.

Answer (score 2):

You always need to know enough c to port headers to your language of choice when there are no ports for a library you want to use yet. Many libraries are written in c since then they can be used from almost all platforms/languages.

Answer (score 2):

Learning C won't necessarily make you a better programmer; there's a superstition that because C is moderately difficult to learn (true) and doesn't have an extensive toolkit (also true), you gain a deeper insight into programming in general (not necessarily true).  C's *just another language*, no better or worse than any other.  You'd get as much benefit learning Fortran.  If you're *really* interested in how things work at the machine/OS level, you'd be better served learning an assembler; just remember that assemblers are specific to their platforms, and some of the concepts that apply to x86 don't apply to other platforms such as MIPS or PPC.

Learning C won't help you much in your day-to-day work in web development.

Having said that, it's always a good idea to pick up new languages if you can, especially languages that are as different as possible from what you're currently using, just because it helps you to learn the difference between a general programming concept vs. a particular language's implementation of that concept.  I've seen plenty of people proficient in a language like C# flail helplessly when forced to work in C because all of their shiny tools are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have experience of object orientated programming in C#, I would recommend learning C++ as opposed to C. It will indeed make you a more rounded programmer. While you could program web sites using C or C++, it's not commonly done for small scale web sites. Facebook created *HipHop for PHP* for instance to improve performance:

> HipHop programmatically transforms your PHP source code into highly optimized C++ and then uses g++ to compile it.

Good luck with your learning, never stop :-)

Answer (score 0):

no :)

C is not targeted for web development

Comment: My friend wrote a web browser and html server in C, don't disregard it

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer, but did your friend wrote a web site in C which is what is asked here?

Comment: I don't doubt it that he could have, but in practice would he?

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: a web browser is a desktop application and an html server is a desktop application too

Comment: @Ali Tarhini, web application is a desktop application too

Comment: how could a web application be a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check this out:

[Native Client](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP8Mo0jGQDk) is an open-source technology for running native code in web applications, with the goal of maintaining the browser neutrality, OS portability, and safety that people expect from web apps.

Comment: IMO a native client using x86 code is misguided. It should use a processor independent low level language like LLVM instead.

Comment: You have a point but it is not what this question is about. Edit: http://nativeclient.googlecode.com/svn/data/site/pnacl.pdf